Looking for solutions to build robots
I'm planning to build a couple of autonomous robots that can be controlled using embedded systems. My goal is to achieve real-time operation with high speed and accuracy, leveraging deep learning (DL) and machine learning (ML) techniques.
I need to simulate the robots' behavior, plan their movements, and visualize their actions in real-time. I also need to integrate DL/ML models for decision-making and control.
I'm considering using ROS2 (Robot Operating System 2) for simulation, planning, and visualization. Is this the right approach? What other solutions should I consider?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
